# Tooltip not showing following click event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tooltip

I am using the following code to show tooltip on a gridview.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Attributes.Add("title", reason[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The tooltip is getting displayed when the page loads, however after a click event occurs the tooltip stops displaying.

Comment: Are you sure you have set EnableViewState="True"?

Comment: In which event you add a title? RowCreated? RowDataBound?

Comment: yes i  have set EnableViewState="True"

Comment: What does the click event do? Do you have ViewState turned off for the page or in the Web.config?

Comment: I am still thinking that it is EnableViewState issue. Are you sure that any of this grid parents aren't setting EnableViewState="false"? In the current version of ASP.NET EnableViewState is implicitly inherited. So if a parent have their enable view state set to false, all of its children has it also, no matter if you try to set it explicitly.

Comment: are you rebinding your gridview after each event?

Comment: @Ivan Zlatanov- I agree. @Geetha- can you describe how you do the databinding in more detail and what the click event does?

Comment: in click event im binding the grid.
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Attributes.Add("title", reason[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }